# Make requests in getStaticProps

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am trying to do a simple fetch of pages from my Wordpress installation in my getStaticProps method:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // get pages!
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/pages");

  return {
    props: {
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

When calling that I get:

**FetchError: request to http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/pages failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000**

So reading the docs a little bit, I know you aren't supposed to make API calls in getStaticProps. However in my case, this is the Wordpress API, not the NextJS API, which I think is what that documentation addresses.

I am able to access my API otherwise just fine. Its like in whatever context calls 'getStaticProps', local host does not exist?

Looking at the wordpress/nextjs example where some API requests are called right within the getStaticProps, the only difference I can see is usage of a GraphQL plugin. I'm assuming that is handling some logic I am overlooking, but I am unsure.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-wordpress

Thank you for any help in advance!
Joe

Comment: That's an external API so there's no issue in making a request to it inside `getStaticProps`. Does the error happen in development, or when you try to build the app? Also, are you certain the WP API is running on that port when the request is made?

Comment: @juliomalves I can request it no problem when the app is running. However getstaticProps is run I don't have access to it at the time